# Examples of $W^{1,n}$ functions that are bounded but not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $B$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n (n\ge 2)$. Is there a function $f\in W^{1,n}(B)$ such that $f\in L^{\infty}(B)$ but $f$ is not continuous in $B$? (solved, see the comments below)

Comment: It is already late (so take this comment with a grain of salt), but I think you should be able to construct such a function the following way. Pick a function with compact support, which is unbounded and in $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, call it $f$. Rescale and translate $f$ to $f_n$ in such a way that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \Vert f_n \Vert_{W^{1,n}(B)}<\infty$ and $\text{supp}(f_n)\subseteq B((1/(2n), 0, \dots,0), 1/(4n^2) )$. Now consider $g=\sum_{n\geq 1} f_n$ which is in $W^{1,n}(B)$. Finally consider $h(x)=\min \{1, g(x)\}$. Then $h\in W^{1,n}(B)$ is bounded and discontinuous at the origin.

Comment: To see the discontinuity part, we note that $\text{essup}f_n = \infty$ (here we use that $f$ is unbounded and so we can rescale and preserve that it is unbounded) and hence the essential supremum of $g$ on the support of $f_n$ is equal to $1$ and the supports accumulate at the origin. On the other hand, if we have $g(x_1, 0,\dots, 0)=0$ for $x_1<0$. Therefore, there is no continuous representative of $g$.

Comment: I should have written $h(x)=\min \{1, \vert g(x)\vert\}$ in my first comment and all the $g$'s in my second comment should be replaced by $h$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Great, thanks. And I have a new question.

Comment: It is considered bad style to ask multiple questions at once. Please consider asking your question in a new post. Also, please include your attempts. Finally I am not sure your first question is fully solved, there are plenty of details to be checked. My comments just give a rough outline.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ok, thanks for your suggestion. And I think your argument is quite clear without any gaps.