# Examples of $W^{2,n}$ functions with bounded but non-continuous derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In the comments of the link [Examples of $W^{1,n}$ functions that are bounded but not continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828851/examples-of-w1-n-functions-that-are-bounded-but-not-continuous), it is shown that there's a function $f\in W^{1,n}(B)$ such that $f\in L^\infty(B)$ but $f$ is not continuous. I'm thinking if this kind of constructions can be generalized to higher-order Sobolev spaces. Say, is there a function $f\in W^{2,n}(B)$ such that $f\in W^{1,\infty}(B)$ but $Df$ is not continuous in $B$?